# what practice is better using pure javascript & css is or using frameworks?

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks

being a student which practice is better using pure javascript & css or frameworks? And which is better for professional field?

Comment: You cannot say this in general. This is project depended. 
You always want to prevent to reinvent the wheel, that's why you should use frameworks and libraryies as much as possible,, imho. As student, it's maybe useful to try stuff with pure js (and maybe jQuery) to figure out how the whole thing works in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to do.

Most of the times, what you want to build is already built by someone else so there is no need (and mostly, no *time*) to re-invent the wheel. Customers want results as soon as possible, so frameworks are good for prototyping.

But to get there, you should first try building things from scratch, so for learning you go with pure CSS and vanilla JS, and then build your knowledge of frameworks.